# Gcc flag for float to int conversion only in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, flags

I am setting some GCC flags and I would need to generate errors only when converting floats/double to integers.

For now `-Werror=float-conversion` generates errors for this but also when converting from double to float which I want to ignore for some reasons.

I know there are multiple flags around conversions, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), but I didn't see any for this.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't get any warnings when I go from double to float, only from float to double. `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wconversion -Wextra -Wall`. Also, see this: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion

Comment: I just tried again:
`conversion to ‘std::vector<float>::value_type {aka float}’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Werror=float-conversion]`

Comment: C++ is not C. Which programming language is it that you are actually using?

Comment: You are right, I am using C++, wrote wrong :/